# App crashes when deleting first item from plist (UITableView)

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, plist

In want to delete rows from my UITableView. The UITableview gets it data from a plist. So when i delete a row i tell the app to delete the corresponding item in the plist (in this case a dictionary. One item of the dictionary (Name) is the title of the UITableViewCell, so the plist looks like so:

```
    Dictionary
         KEY(Name)
           ITEM
         KEY(Description)
           ITEM
    Dictionary
          KEY(name)
             ....
```

)
And i use the following code to delete the rows, it works fine, apart from the very first row. The app crashes when i try to delete the first row, i have no idea why.

```
int g = indexPath.row;
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"];
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        [array removeObjectAtIndex:g];
        [array writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Comment: How do you know that the array has a `g`th element?

Comment: @chris it must have the gth element, how could i even delete the row if i lt didnt exist?

Comment: @sergio crash log is empty, crash is EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` usually means that the program tried to use an object that had already been deallocated.

I doubt that such object could be `array`, since it has just been allocated when you try and remove its 0-th element. You could easily check this by adding an NSLog trace like here:

```
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSLog(@"Array count: %d", [array count]);
    [array removeObjectAtIndex:g];
```

In general, to determine which object could be, my suggestion is enable `NSZombies`. You can do that by running the app [using the "Zombies" performance tool](http://www.thinketg.com/company/blogs/11-04-30/XCode_4_NSZombies_and_how_to_summon_them.aspx), or [setting an environment variable](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSZombieEnabled).

You will get a much more descriptive error message that will also identify the type of object that you tried to access.

Comment: ok i fixed the problem, it was something very stupid that wans't in the posted code, still thank you!